# Error while running a python3 script on startup

Tags: bash, scripts, python3, init.d

I'm trying to run a python script ( /home/user/Desktop/file.py ) on startup by making a bash script ( /etc/init.d/file.bash ) that runs the python script

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  start)
    echo "Starting"
    /home/user/Desktop/file.py
    ;;
  stop)
    echo "Stopping"
    killall python3.5
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: service file.bash{start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

and I made a symbolic link of file.bash and put it in /etc/rc5.d/S{NN}file.bash but for some reason when the service starts I get an error

```
● file.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/file.bash; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-12-11 14:49:45 EET; 29min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   Process: 1285 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/file.bash start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:     protocol_display.Display.__init__(self, *args, **keys)
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 85, in __init__
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:     name, host, displayno, screenno = connect.get_display(display)
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/support/connect.py", line 72, in get_display
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:     return mod.get_display(display)
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/Xlib/support/unix_connect.py", line 61, in get_display
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]:     raise error.DisplayNameError(display)
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC file.bash[1285]: Xlib.error.DisplayNameError: Bad display name ""
Dec 11 14:49:45 ****-PC systemd[1]: Started file.service.
```

when I start the file.bash ( `$ /etc/init.d/file.bash start` ) I don't get any errors

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.1 and python3.5

### Edit:

the error is in ( `from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener` )

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import socket
import subprocess
import time
import os
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener # <
```

but the script works correctly when I call it in the terminal

Comment: Does the script work if you call it from terminal, and if so does it really get a new screen instance from Xserver? If yes maybe it gets run before the Xserver starts, if no there must be something wrong in your script. My guess.

Comment: I'm not sure about xserver but my script works correctly when i call it from the terminal

Comment: Well that is at least what the errors hint at from what I can see here.

Comment: hmm so if it does run before the Xserver how do I fix it

Comment: maybe setting the `$DISPLAY` variable to `:0` should fix it : /

Comment: I'm admittedly not firm enough with the Xlib so I cant tell you a proper solution, only tell you my thoughts when I see the error messages and making a guess.